# Always Display Date In ZedGraph Axis?

Tags: c#, zedgraph

```
var p = zgc.GraphPane;
p.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;
```

My date values are in a PointPairList in XDate format.
When I zoom in my graph, the tick labels only show time values and not date values.  I want to be able to always show a date and time so I know what date I am looking at.

If you could help me solve this simple problem, I would appreciate it, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adjusting the XAxis.Scale.MajorUnit or XAxis.Scale.MinorUnit values?